# Virgo's application deployer API crashing on undeploy

Tags: java, eclipse-virgo

I'm trying to have a bundle deploy other bundles and start them using the org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.ApplicationDeployer mostly like the admin app (org.eclipse.virgo.apps.admin) is doing. I've inspired myself from the admin console code and do :
deploymentIdentity = applicationDeployer(bundleFile.getURI(), new DeploymentOptions(false,false,true));

and :

applicationDeployer.undeploy(deploymentIdentity);

It works, but once in a while, it crash with the exception :

```
    service proxy has been destroyed
org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.ServiceProxyDestroyedException: service proxy has been destroyed
        at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceDynamicInterceptor$ServiceLookUpCallback.doWithRetry(ServiceDynamicInterceptor.java:105) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:83) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceDynamicInterceptor.lookupService(ServiceDynamicInterceptor.java:430) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceDynamicInterceptor.getTarget(ServiceDynamicInterceptor.java:415) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.LocalBundleContextAdvice.invoke(LocalBundleContextAdvice.java:59) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) ~[na:na]
```

I've wired the applicationDeployer at first with a service ref, then with a osgi:listener. In both implementations, the applicationDeployer reference never come back, but still works fine in the virgo's admin webapp.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Glym Normington for awnsering me on Eclipse forum : http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/225554/